# Amazon EC2 - Not able to find / mount EBS volume partition

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, redhat, partition, amazon-ebs

I have a linux instance to which a ebs volumne of 20GB has been attached.

**The web-console volume page shows:**

```
20 GiB gp2 snap-b3a87xyz  in-use i-cd5b9999 (myinstance):/dev/sda1 (attached)
```

**The web-console instance page shows:**

```
Root device type: ebs
Root device: /dev/sda1
Block devices: /dev/sda1
```

**On Command Line (20GB partition is not shown as mounted):**

```
# df -kh
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda2      6.0G  803M  5.3G  14% /
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.8G   17M  1.8G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

**But i see the 20GB partition available here(xvda below):**

```
# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

 202        0   20971520 xvda
 202        1       1024 xvda1
 202        2    6291456 xvda2
```

**So, I tried mounting it, but i get error message:**

```
# mount /dev/xvda /mnt/ebs
mount: /dev/xvda is already mounted or /mnt/ebs busy
```

**Question:**
I cannot find the 20GB mounted partition - why?

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/xvda` is the volume root.  It looks like (and fdisk would confirm) you have unpartitioned space on it.

Also, partitioned EBS volumes are odd.  To preserve the sanity of you and everyone who uses your deployment, consider provisioning a new EBS volume for your data space and using it unpartitioned instead.  If you want to resize the root filesystem, you'll need to resize the partition, or possibly create a new AMI.